# How to ignore certain objects in admin view of model

Tags: django, django-models

How can I ignore objects of a model in an admin view, with certain attribute values?

For instance: Don't list objects where model.name = "Fire"

Comment: I didn't get it. Are you looking to remove some model from django admin?

Comment: Maybe you can try to override the `get_queryset` method in order to exclude objects that have name='Fire'

Answer (score 1):

In Admin.py you can override `get_queryset` and call `exclude` methods of `QuerySets`  as below.

Below, queryset will exclude Post objects whose title starts with `hello`
In you case queryset would be `queryset.exclude(name="Fire")`

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ["title", "body"]

    def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request, *args, **kwargs)
        #queryset = queryset.exclude(pk=1)
        queryset = queryset.exclude(title__startswith="hello")
        #queryset = queryset.exclude(name="Fire")
        # Write your own needs

        return queryset
```